# Why aren't my Scala futures executing in parallel?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, future

I'm trying to run a series of dumb Scala `Future`s in parallel. I have the following code, which I expect to take ~10 seconds:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{Success, Failure}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def scalaFoo = Future {
  Thread.sleep(10*1000) // sleep for 10 seconds
  List(1,2,3)
}

def scalaBar = Future {
  Thread.sleep(10*1000)
  List(4,5,6)
}

def scalaBaz = Future {
  Thread.sleep(10*1000)
  List(7,8,9)
}

val flatRes: Future[List[Int]] = for {
  scalaFooRes <- scalaFoo 
  scalaBarRes <- scalaBar
  scalaBazRes <- scalaBaz
} yield (scalaFooRes ++ scalaBarRes ++ scalaBazRes)

flatRes onComplete {
  case Success(li) => println(li.foldLeft(0)(_ + _))
  case Failure(e) => println(e.getMessage)
}
```

But what I find is that the `onComplete` takes ~30 seconds, so my jobs are running sequentially.

How can I make them run in parallel? Why aren't they running in parallel now?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to create them before the for expression, otherwise they wont run in parallel. If you change the methods to vals, it should work.

Comment: Indeed. The Futures must be created (and started) before going into the for-comprehension. When using a 'val' the computation of the Future starts immediately (or at least it's being scheduled immediately). With a 'def' (method) it is started after it is called. Another observation: why creating a List of Lists in the yield, and than flatten it? Can just as well append the lists using '++'. I would recon that's faster.

Answer (score 6):

You also could use Future.sequence:

```
def scalaFoo = Future {
  Thread.sleep(3*1000) // sleep for 10 seconds
  List(1,2,3)
}

def scalaBar = Future {
  Thread.sleep(3*1000)
  List(4,5,6)
}

def scalaBaz = Future {
  Thread.sleep(3*1000)
  List(7,8,9)
}
Future.sequence(List(scalaFoo, scalaBar, scalaBaz)).onComplete({
  case Success(li) => println(li.flatten.sum)
  case Failure(e) => println(e.getMessage)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can run these futures in parallel declaring variables first:

```
val foo = scalaFoo
val bar = scalaBar
val baz = scalaBaz
```

And then doing for:

```
for {
  scalaFooRes <- foo 
  scalaBarRes <- bar
  scalaBazRes <- baz
} ...
```

Comment: But why? I put a print statement in each of the `scala*` functions and one directly after the `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` in your example were defined and found the prints out of order. Why would the execution here be out of order?

Comment: @erip As is usually the case with concurrent programming, there is no guarantee around execution order when the futures are executing in parallel.

Comment: @sheunis the `for` is just syntactic sugar for `flatMap`, which means that a future will only run after the previous finishes. Creating them beforehand and assigning to a variable circumvents this issue.

Comment: Adding to nmat's response, if you unwravel the sugar, you'll see the call chain has to wait for the previous future to complete before moving forward: `func1.flatMap(l1 => func2.flatMap(l2 => func3.flatMap(l3 => Future { l1 ++ l2 ++ l3 })))`